# What does it mean 'to have a day for someone'?

Tags: meaning

> Need to quit the sipping syrup, 'fore you in the dirt
>
> Remember that's why they said they got a day for Yams

As you can see it's from a rap song, and I can't find the meaning of **'to have a day for someone'** execpt to have one's day. Can you please explain me what does it mean?

Comment: @cobaltduck, A$AP Yams is a rapper

Comment: Accoring to [this article](https://genius.com/a/jaden-smith-compares-himself-to-a-dragon-ball-z-legend-on-goku), the meaning is to quit abusing codeine (syrup) before you are dead and buried (in the dirt) because that is how "they" claim A$AP Yams died.  However, I have never heard "got a day for" used like this, it might be a vernacular term from Rap culture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Having a day for" someone or something means a day of celebration or remembrance in honor of that person or thing, such as a birthday or holiday.

Comment: Except in this case, it seems the celebration was a funeral?

Comment: I'm not clear that this is what the song means, but I don't really know the song.  But anyway, it doesn't have to be a *happy* celebration; it can be a day of remembrance and honor as well. It just means the day's activities are dedicated to that person or concept.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym "'fore you in the dirt" means before you are buried, as in dead. Cobaltduck is right

Comment: To be honest, I did not know either until I looked it up- see my comment on the question.  And feel free to steal my link to enhance your answer, if you'd like.